# How to get status code for PATCH method in angular?

Tags: angular, rest, httpresponse

I am making a webservice API call using PATCH method. If the patch is successful then it will return a 204 status code. With the help of status code, I write logic in my component. But HTTPResponse is coming as null when I do a console.log. How do I get the status code in this case to write my logic?

```
public invokePatchRequest(): void {
        this.myService
        .invokePatchRequest('John')
        .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$))
        .subscribe(
            (response: HttpResponse<any>) => {
                if (response.status === 204 ) {
                    console.log('Display Success Message');
                } 
            },
            (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                // Handle Error
            }
        );
    }
```

In the above code, response is coming as null. So I am not able to compare the status code. Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default HttpClient's `patch` method observes body of the response. To get a full response (including status), you can add `observe: 'response'` to the options object when calling the method.

For example:

```js
const url = 'http://anything.com';
const body = {};

this.http.patch<ResponseBodyType>(url, body, {observe: 'response'}); // will return Observable<HttpResponse<ResponseBodyType>>
```